# using Change on an Input and then modifying the input's ATTR?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given:

**html**

```
<input checked="checked" class="list_completed_checkbox" id="list_item_completed" name="list_item[completed]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.list_completed_checkbox').change(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

When you check or uncheck the checkbox, Why isn't the disabled attr being applied to the input?

Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me (in Chrome, IE6-9 and Firefox 4): http://jsfiddle.net/Z9uyD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/qYe96/

Perhaps something else is interfering?

Answer (score 1):

i don't think an input has a change event. you might want to do a focus or blur depending on what you need.

```
$('.list_completed_checkbox').blur(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: Inputs definitely do have change events... you can see the OPs example working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9uyD/

Comment: the change even is triggering, the attr isn't being applied though

Comment: @TheExit - Can you pinpoint any other parts of your code that could be causing this to fail? Is there any other code in your click event handler?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    $('.list_completed_checkbox').change(function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });
```

Comment: @TheExit I hope this will for all